# c++ How to use parent class fields in child class

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class CCircularBuffer {
 protected:
  size_t size_ = 0;
  size_t max_size_{};
  T* values_;
  size_t begin_ = 0;
  size_t end_ = 0;
  Alloc alloc_;

 public:
  virtual void resize(size_t size);
};
```

And the class that inherits it:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
class CCircularBufferExt: public CCircularBuffer<T, Alloc> {
 public:
    void resize(size_t n);

};
```

But when I try to use fields from the CCircularBuffer class, the compiler does not see them:

Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'values_'

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
void CCircularBufferExt<T, Alloc>::resize(size_t n) {
    values_ = alloc_.allocate(n);
}
```

What could be the problem? And am I using inheritance correctly?

I thought the problem was that the compiler doesn't see the CCircularBuffer class, but it seems to see it anyway...

Error screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2w2y.png)

Comment: I am not sure why, but explicitly referring to the base class solves it: `CCircularBuffer<T, Alloc>::values_ = CCircularBuffer<T, Alloc>::alloc_.allocate(n);`

Comment: @nielsen It's because templates are involved. You can have `CCircularBuffer` specialization that has different set of members, so compiler doesn't just assume unqualified name to be a member. FWIW, `this->values_` works just as well (or a `using` declaration), so you don't have to explicitly spell out base class name every time.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, that makes sense. You should write an answer.